# Is there a way to configure the details of MSVS static code analysis?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, configuration, code-analysis

Static code analysis tool in MSVS (for C++) has plenty of false positives, and some of them are in Windows SDK files. Is there a way to configure it in order to improve quality and ignore stable SDK files?

Comment: didn't go very far since starting this topic. today I came upon Raymond Chen's (aka The Old New Thing) blog entry http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/06/14/10024197.aspx which pointed to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3bbz7tz.aspx. Still, nothing new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found what I was looking for - here is the answer directly from MSDN's http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyhb0b82.aspx (VS2010 specific):

```
#include <codeanalysis\warnings.h>
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning ( disable : ALL_CODE_ANALYSIS_WARNINGS )
#include <third-party include files here>
#pragma warning( pop )
```

Comment: You can also disable a particular code analysis warning too, for instance 6385 that occurs in some of the microsoft header files.